# Not An App Admin, Developer or Tester FBAdView iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to integrate `FBAdView` for Banner Ad in my application. I am using the following code to ad banner ad.

```
var fbAdView = FBAdView.init(placementID: "[AD_PLACEMENT_ID_HERE]", adSize: kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner, rootViewController: self)
fbAdView.delegate = self
fbAdView.loadAd()
// Frames and all are set
self.view.addSubview(fbAdView)
```

But the ad loading is continuously failing with the following error. I am running on actual device(not Simulator) and in the device my fb account is logged in facebook application, and my FB account is a developer for the application. The error follows:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=2000 "Server Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Server Error, FBAdErrorDetailKey={
    code = 33001;
    message = "Initial request from a bundle must come from a App Admin, Developer or Tester.";
    type = OAuthException;
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/network_ads_common/";
}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: any solutions? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I contacted the developer support of facebook. They asked me to try running the sample project in the device after changing the bundle ID and the AD_PLACEMENT_ID to the one used in my app. Then the ad loaded. Then I tried again with my application and it worked!!!

Comment: @HarikrishnanT cool bro. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just check your `bundle ID` and the `AD_PLACEMENT_ID` make sure it correct

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and no solutions mentioned here worked for me. In the end either xCode restart or trying on different device helped.